# Remove a field from an sObject object in Apex

Tags: apex

Essentially what I'm looking for is the Apex equivalent of the javascript [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

---

The reason I want to do this is that I want to store data in the standard `Contact.Email` field, but I need to handle the possibility that the data coming in could cause a save error with a INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS status code. I want to be able to detect the error, and retry the upsert with the value provided for the email address being stored into a new custom text field instead. To do this, I need to clear the value in the object's `Email` field. Since this is an upsert operation, I don't want to set the value of the field to `NULL` since that will clear the value in the database, which I would want to leave intact if it is already present.

Basically, what I'm looking for is the easiest way to get from:

```
Contact:{LastName=LastName, Email=FirstName.LastName@@Company.com, Id=003p000000LO97zAAD, ...}
```

to:

```
Contact:{LastName=LastName, Email__c=FirstName.LastName@@Company.com, Id=003p000000LO97zAAD, ...}
```

and specifically not:

```
Contact:{LastName=LastName, Email=null, Email__c=FirstName.LastName@@Company.com, Id=003p000000LO97zAAD, ....}
```

Comment: You're going to need to do it in a couple steps.

Comment: This capability does not exist in apex today. One way or another you'll need to construct a new SObject instance to do this

Comment: Hi Martin, thoughts on renaming this question to use the word "sobject" instead of "object"? When I read `object` I thought you meant needing to use metadata api to physical alter the structure of the object/table, not  your apex variable. Or re-phrase as "object variable"? Thanks!

Comment: @DougAyers I was using the term [object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes.htm#!) in the sense of an instance of a class, but specifying that the object inherits from `sObject` does give you more to work with, and I was specifically concerned about the effects on DML operations, so I'd be willing to update the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can be done using combination of `serialize` and `deserialize` tricks with SObject and Map. In short, you serialize your original sobject into JSON then deserialize it into untyped Map then modify the map's keys to add/remove any fields you want - or don't want - set. Then serialize the map back into JSON then deserialize it into your typed SObject.

```
// start with your original sobject
Account acct1 = new Account(
    name = 'Turkey',
    type = 'Gobble'
);
System.debug( 'Step 1. Account object: ' + acct1 );

// Step 2. Get map of the sobject fields
// In this variant, the populated fields map is read-only so pass it into another map to get an editable copy
Map<String, Object> acctMap1 = new Map<String, Object>( acct1.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() );
System.debug( 'Step 2. Account populated fields map: ' + acctMap1 );

// Another way to do Step 2 is good ol' serialize/deserialize trick
Map<String, Object> acctMap2 = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped( JSON.serialize( acct1 ) );
System.debug( 'Another way to do Step 2. Account serialized as json then deserialized back into untyped map: ' + acctMap2 );

// Step 3. Remove any fields you don't want
acctMap1.remove( 'Type' );
System.debug( 'Step 3. Remove undesired field "Type" from map: ' + acctMap1 );

// Step 4. Convert the map into sobject using the good ol' serialize/deserialize trick
Account acct2 = (Account) JSON.deserialize( JSON.serialize( acctMap1 ), Account.class );
System.debug( 'Step 4. Account after serializing map of our desired fields into json then deserializing the json back into sobject: ' + acct2 );
```

Comment: How would one go about doing this kind of thing with several layers of nested JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you try to upsert your records via the [Database.upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm?search_text=database.upsert) method.

```
Database.UpsertResult resultList = Database.upsert(contactList, Contact.Id, false);
```

`resultList` will now contain your results.

```
// New list of contacts
List<Contact> contactList2 = new List<Contact>();

// Check each result for success
for(Integer i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++)
{
    Database.UpsertResult result = resultList.get(i);

    if(!result.isSuccess())
    {
        for(Database.error singleError : result.getErrors())
        {
            if(singleError.getStatusCode() == Database.StatusCode.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
            {
                Contact c = contactList.get(i);
                c.Email__c = c.Email;
                contactList2.add(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check out [Database.UpsertResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_upsertresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_upsertresult) and [Database.Error](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_error.htm#apex_methods_system_database_error).

Basically your allowing SF to upsert each row individually and then evaluate the results. You should - of course - handle other errors as well.

Comment: So far so good, the problem is with the next step though. How do you get rid of the `Email` field in `c` so you can re-upsert that object without erasing a value already stored in the database or re-encountering the same error?

Comment: @martin I guess you can instantiate a new contact instead of using the one in the list: `Contact c = new Contact(Id = contactList.get(i).Id);`

Comment: @martin Or re-query the records that fail instead of adding them to contactList2. Then populate your custom email field and upsert.

Comment: @Novarg I agree that this will probably require the construction of a new object instance.

Comment: @Christoph These records are coming in through push notifications from an external system. In this case I do also have the ability to make a callout to re-query these records, but I wouldn't want to have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

*Came across a different use-case for needing to do this:*

There was a long-running, Stateful Batch Job that queried records in the `start()`, modified them in the `execute()` and updated them in the `finish()`.

This resulted in a [Lost Update concurrency problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control) if a user modified any of the queried fields while the batch was running.

**Wrote a generic utility function:**

```java
public static List<Object> removeProperties(Type objectType, List<Object> objects, String[] propertiesToRemove){
   // serialize / deserialize into a generic List<Map<String, Object>>
   List<Object> deserializedList = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(objects));

    // For each object, remove each property
    for (Object deserialized : deserializedList) {
        Map<string, Object> obj = (Map<string, Object>) deserialized;
        for(string property : propertiesToRemove){
           obj.remove(property);
        }
    }
    // serialize / deserialize back to object type
    return (List<Object>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(deserializedList), objectType); 
}

//... test
Account[] ogList = new Account[]{
   new Account(Name='foo1', Website = 'testing.com')
};


Account[] cleanedList = (List<Account>) removeProperties(
    List<Account>.class, ogList, new string[]{'Website'}
);

System.debug(cleanedList);

System.assertEquals(cleanedList.size(), ogList.size());
system.assert(cleanedList[0].Website == null);
```

This is basically the same as the `@Doug Ayers` answer, but maybe more performant for bulk use cases.