# Is there a way to remove a field from a SObject variable for update?

Tags: apex

Suppose I have a SObject A__c, it has two fields b__c and c__c.

Now I have:

```
A__c a = [Select Id, b__c, c__c From A__c limit 1];
//Suppose a.b__c = 'a', and a.c__c = 'a' right now. 
a.b__c = 'b';
a.c__c = 'c';
if(/*...*/) {
    //here I want to remove c__c field value so I can only update b__c.
    //But a.c__c apparently won't work here.
    //What I want to do is only update a.b__c to 'b' but keep the value of a.c__c here.  
}
update a;
```

Is it possible to simply get rid of a.c__c in the variable value? Something like `delete a.c__c`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct answer is "no." There's only one way to unload a field from an sObject, and that's to call `clear`, which, as the name implies, remove all fields completely. You need to construct a new version of A__c somehow, either by way of `new A__c(...)` or re-querying the database, or storing a temporary copy via `clone`, or through a JSON round-trip, etc. The preferred method would be to not change the field if it doesn't need to be to begin with. It's almost always possible to shuffle around the code such that you don't get any unwanted updates.

Comment: Thank you for that. It is pretty generalised code reading from a external source which is coming in a JSON format. I find it hard to getting rid of them in the first instance. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't completely understand the question, do you want to clear the value from the field a.c__c on update? in which case you can just clear the value like this a.c__c = null or a.c__c = ''

Otherwise what is the harm in keeping a.c__c in the update statement if you have not changed the value, if say a.c__c = 'c' and you update the record, that value will not change.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for the confusion here. I edited my question according to your confusion. What I want to achieve is to ignore c__c's value in this case - which means I want to keep the original value of c__c field instead of clearing it up.

Comment: Then just leave it, the update statement won't change the value of c__c unless your code block does so, therefore you will keep your original value. If because this is a contrived code block and you have a bunch of other things going on that you don't want to post here and you want to rollback to the original value then just store it in a variable



string originalCVal = a.c__c; 

if(/*...*/) {
a.c__c = originalCVal; 
};

update a;

Comment: If you really really need to do this, there is another answer on stackexchange for this that I have found which makes sense, you need to deserialize the object and reserialize after removing the offending field but I would really consider whether you need to do this.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199784/remove-a-field-from-an-sobject-object-in-apex

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different way of tackeling the issue. I had to make updates on a record based on new info, and would generally always have to set the fields in the integration message that I received. Until there was a specific instance where we should NOT update that field and keep the version in Salesforce. Unsetting the field was not an option, as it is not available in SF.

What we ended up doing is looking up the record (just like what is done in the example) and simply overwriting the value of the field with the old record's value in stead of unsetting.